# Async/await javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react, react-native

Como posso deixar o código abaixo menos bagunçado com asnyc/await?

```
class Backend {
   getUsers(callback){
      const database = firebase.database().ref('users/')
      const onReceive = (data) => {
          callback({
             data
          )}
      }
      database.on('child_added', onReceive)
   }
}

Backend.getUsers((data) => {
   console.log(data)
   // Coloquei o console.log() só por colocar mesmo
})
```

Comment: Você gostaria de carregar todos os usuários de uma vez ou ficar "ouvindo" a cada usuário inserido?

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro você terá que criar um método estático para poder acessá-lo sem criar uma instancia de `Backend` utilizando `static`.

Agora para poder utilizar `await` você precisará usar promises. Você poderia usar o modificador `async` no seu método para transformar o retorno de `getUsers` em um resolve de uma promise, mas como o valor a ser retornado está dentro de uma callback (`onReceive`), não tem como você retornar o valor com a declaração `return`. Você terá que recorrer a criar um objeto `Promise` para assim poder utilizar os callbacks `resolve` ou `reject` dentro do callback de `database.on`.

```
class Backend {
   static getUsers() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const database = firebase.database().ref('users/')
          database.on('child_added', data => resolve({ data }))
      })
   }
}

async function imprimirUsers() {
    const data = await Backend.getUsers()
    console.log(data)
}

imprimirUsers()
```

Comment: Um adicional seria adicionar um `try/catch` para capturar os erros, caso tenha: Segue exemplo: https://jsbin.com/jeyabikoqo/edit?js

Comment: De alguma forma só esta retornando 1 usuário

Comment: Essa solução usando Promise não funciona, uma vez que o callback é chamado múltiplas vezes, uma para cada nó adicionado (`child_added`).
Esse examplo ajuda a entender o que acontece: http://jsbin.com/gemepay/3/edit?js,console